# How to compare dataframe unique values with a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda dataframe column, and I want to check if all values in my column come from another list.

For example, I want to check whether all values in my column are `A` or `B` and nothing else. My code should return true for the following inputs:

```
myValues = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','B','A'],columns=['Col']) # True
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A'],columns=['Col']) # True
df = pd.DataFrame(['B'],columns=['Col']) # True
df = pd.DataFrame(['B','C'],columns=['Col']) # False
```

Comment: if you convert the list to a series then you can do something like `s = pd.Series(myValues)` and then `s.isin(df['Col']).all()` for each df

Comment: Actually you can just do `df['Col1'].isin(myValues).all()` for all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and pass your list to generate a boolean array and with `all` to return whether all values present:

```
In [146]:    
myValues = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','B','A'],columns=['Col']) # True
print(df['Col'].isin(myValues).all())
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','A'],columns=['Col']) # True
print(df['Col'].isin(myValues).all())
df = pd.DataFrame(['B'],columns=['Col']) # True
print(df['Col'].isin(myValues).all())
df = pd.DataFrame(['B','C'],columns=['Col']) # False
print(df['Col'].isin(myValues).all())


True
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
df.eval('Col in @myValues')
```

Demo:

```
In [78]: pd.DataFrame(['A','B','B','A'],columns=['Col']).eval('Col in @myValues')
Out[78]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool

In [79]: pd.DataFrame(['A','A'],columns=['Col']).eval('Col in @myValues')
Out[79]:
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool

In [80]: pd.DataFrame(['B'],columns=['Col']).eval('Col in @myValues')
Out[80]:
0    True
dtype: bool

In [81]: pd.DataFrame(['B','C'],columns=['Col']).eval('Col in @myValues')
Out[81]:
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```